# How do I set colors for three js instanced objects?

Tags: three.js, aframe, virtual-reality

I have an a-frame component that leverages three js instancing to render a large number of spheres efficiently. Based on examples from the three js library such as https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_instancing_scatter.html, I should be able to set the colors for each of the instanced renderings individually. I thought I had followed the example but my per instance colors are not taking effect.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('spheres', {
    schema: {
        count: {type: 'number'},
        radius: {type: 'number'},
        scale: {type: 'number'},
        colors: {type: 'array'},
        positions: {type: 'array'}
    },
    init: function() {
        const {count, radius, scale, colors, positions} = this.data;  

        const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

        const geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( radius, 3, 2 );
        const instancedGeometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(geometry); 
        var instanceColors = [];

        for ( var i = 0; i < count; i ++ ) {

            instanceColors.push( Math.random() );
            instanceColors.push( Math.random() );
            instanceColors.push( Math.random() );

        }
        instancedGeometry.setAttribute("instanceColor", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( new Float32Array( instanceColors ), 3 ))

        instancedGeometry.computeVertexNormals();

        material.vertexColors = true;

        const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        const mesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh( instancedGeometry, material, count );

        for ( var i = 0; i < count; i ++ ) {

            this.setMatrix(positions[i], scale)( matrix );
            mesh.setMatrixAt( i, matrix );

        }

        this.el.object3D.add( mesh );
    },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One way: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_instancing_modified.html

Comment: @WestLangley I saw that example but it was less friendly looking. Can you explain which part is responsible for setting the individual colors?

Comment: You can pass `InstancedBufferGeometry` to `Mesh`, but `InstancedMesh` expects `BufferGeometry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work with the following based on @prisoner849 example. I had to use MeshPhongMaterial rather than MeshNormalMaterial. Not quite sure why. Also not sure why I need to use an InstancedBufferAttribute and a BufferAttribute for the colors. maybe @prisoner849 can follow up with details. This solution is a bit ugly, hopefully three will provide a cleaner way to tweak instanced colors soon, or maybe there is a better way already and I just dont know about it

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('spheres', {
    schema: {
        count: {type: 'number'},
        radius: {type: 'number'},
        scale: {type: 'number'},
        colors: {type: 'array'},
        positions: {type: 'array'}
    },
    init: function() {
        const {count, radius, scale, colors, positions} = this.data;  

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(radius);
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ flatShading: true });
        var colorParsChunk = [
            'attribute vec3 instanceColor;',
            'varying vec3 vInstanceColor;',
            '#include <common>'
        ].join( '\n' );

        var instanceColorChunk = [
            '#include <begin_vertex>',
            '\tvInstanceColor = instanceColor;'
        ].join( '\n' );

        var fragmentParsChunk = [
            'varying vec3 vInstanceColor;',
            '#include <common>'
        ].join( '\n' );

        var colorChunk = [
            'vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse * vInstanceColor, opacity );'
        ].join( '\n' );

        material.onBeforeCompile = function ( shader ) {

            shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader
                .replace( '#include <common>', colorParsChunk )
                .replace( '#include <begin_vertex>', instanceColorChunk );

            shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader
                .replace( '#include <common>', fragmentParsChunk )
                .replace( 'vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );', colorChunk );

        };

        var instanceColors = [];

        for ( var i = 0; i < count; i ++ ) {

            instanceColors.push( Math.random() );
            instanceColors.push( Math.random() );
            instanceColors.push( Math.random() );

        }

        const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        const mesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh( geometry, material, count );

        var instanceColorsBase = new Float32Array(instanceColors.length);
        instanceColorsBase.set(instanceColors);
        geometry.setAttribute( 'instanceColor', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( new Float32Array( instanceColors ), 3 ) );
        geometry.setAttribute( 'instanceColorBase', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array( instanceColorsBase ), 3 ) );

        for ( var i = 0; i < count; i ++ ) {

            this.setMatrix(positions[i], scale)( matrix );
            mesh.setMatrixAt( i, matrix );

        }

        this.el.object3D.add( mesh );
    },
    setMatrix: function( pos, scaler ) {

        var position = new THREE.Vector3();
        var rotation = new THREE.Euler();
        var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
        var scale = new THREE.Vector3();

        return function ( matrix ) {

            position.x = pos[0];
            position.y = pos[1];
            position.z = pos[2];

            rotation.x = 0;
            rotation.y = 0;
            rotation.z = 0;

            quaternion.setFromEuler( rotation );

            scale.x = scale.y = scale.z = scaler;

            matrix.compose( position, quaternion, scale );

        };

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the actual same attribute 'color', like in the example (which is

> `blossomGeometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( color, 3 ) );`

Because I think it's quite important that the name of the attribute is 'color'.

Comment: I did try 'color' and it still didnt work. I was wondering the same thing, I'm not sure how three js recognizes the color attribute with instanced objects. I think that is probably the issue but Im not sure how to fix it

Comment: @DavidStein Works as expected: https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/wvKqpRY